# My program compiles, but the time and date will not update. Can someone show me where I am going off course

Tags: c

I completed my code and ran it through code blocks with no errors and it shows the date and time that I have in the code at the command prompt screen, but for some reason it will not update.  Can someone point me in the right direction or show me what I am doing wrong. Here is the problem that I thought that I had solved:

> Write a function called clockKeeper that takes as its argument a
>   dateAndTime structure. The function should call the timeUpdate
>   function, and if the time reaches midnight, the function should call
>   the dateUpdate function to switch over to the next day. Have the
>   function return the updated dateAndTime structure and output it to the
>   terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int dt;

struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

struct time
{
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
    int hour;
};

struct dateAndTime {
     struct date sdate;
     struct time stime;
     };

struct dateAndTime  clockKeeper (struct dateAndTime dt)
{
    struct time  timeUpdate (struct time  now); {
    printf ("timeUpdate\n");
    return now;
     }

    struct date  dateUpdate (struct date  today); {
    printf ("dateUpdate\n");
    return today;
    }    

    dt.stime = timeUpdate (dt.stime);

    if ( dt.stime.hour == 0  &&  dt.stime.minutes == 0  &&
         dt.stime.seconds == 0 )
         dt.sdate = dateUpdate (dt.sdate);

    return  dt;
}

int main (void)

    int dt1;
    int dt2;

{
    struct dateAndTime  dt1 = { { 12, 31, 2004 }, { 23, 59, 59 } };
    struct dateAndTime  dt2 = { { 2, 28, 2008 }, { 23, 59, 58 } };

    printf ("Current date and time is %.2i/%.2i/%.2i "
        "%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n",
        dt1.sdate.month, dt1.sdate.day, dt1.sdate.year,
        dt1.stime.hour,
        dt1.stime.minutes, dt1.stime.seconds);

    dt1 = clockKeeper (dt1);

    printf ("Updated date and time is %.2i/%.2i/%.2i "
        "%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n\n",
        dt1.sdate.month, dt1.sdate.day, dt1.sdate.year,
        dt1.stime.hour, dt1.stime.minutes, dt1.stime.seconds);

    printf ("Current date and time is %.2i/%.2i/%.2i "
        "%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n",
        dt2.sdate.month, dt2.sdate.day, dt2.sdate.year,
        dt2.stime.hour, dt2.stime.minutes, dt2.stime.seconds);

    dt2 = clockKeeper (dt2);

    printf ("Updated date and time is %.2i/%.2i/%.2i "
        "%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n\n",
        dt2.sdate.month, dt2.sdate.day, dt2.sdate.year,
        dt2.stime.hour, dt2.stime.minutes, dt2.stime.seconds);

    printf ("Current date and time is %.2i/%.2i/%.2i "
        "%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n",
        dt2.sdate.month, dt2.sdate.day, dt2.sdate.year,
        dt2.stime.hour, dt2.stime.minutes, dt2.stime.seconds);

    dt2 = clockKeeper (dt2);

    printf ("Updated date and time is %.2i/%.2i/%.2i "
        "%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n\n",
        dt2.sdate.month, dt2.sdate.day, dt2.sdate.year,
        dt2.stime.hour, dt2.stime.minutes, dt2.stime.seconds);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of passing by reference vs. passing by value?

Comment: Does it show timeUpdate and dateUpdate in the command line screen?

Comment: If this compiles with no errors or warnings, I would seriously question the compiler.

Comment: What C compiler are you using? Because I get errors trying to compiled your code. Lines 28 and 33 seem fishy, where you appear to try and do something with nested functions (??, not supported in C), and have semi-colons at awkward places at those lines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to define a function `timeUpdate` inside the definition of `clockKeeper`.  When you write (changed indentation to de-obfuscate):

```
struct dateAndTime  clockKeeper (struct dateAndTime dt)
{
    struct time  timeUpdate (struct time  now);
    { /* This brace may as well be deleted.  */
    printf ("timeUpdate\n");
    return now;
    } /* along with this one. */
...
```

you are defining the function `clockKeeper` in which you declare the existence of the function timeUpdate and two statements that are executed in clockKeeper.  The only thing clockKeeper will ever do is those two statements.  If you want to define the function `timeUpdate`, you need to move it outside the definition of clockKeeper and remove the semi-colon before the opening brace.  There are probably many other issues with your code, but this is a good place to start.